# datatable filterr date calendar error

Tags: primefaces

My problem is the filter date don´t work

```
 <p:column headerText="Fecha Alta" sortBy="#{p.fechaAlta}" filterBy="#{p.fechaAlta}" filterMatchMode="equals">
                       <f:facet name="filter">
                           <p:calendar  pattern="MM/dd/yyyy">
                             <p:ajax event="dateSelect" oncomplete="PF('tablaP').filter()" update="tablaP"/>
                         </p:calendar>
                       </f:facet>
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{p.fechaAlta}"  >
                                      <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
                           </h:outputText></f:facet>
```

Help me.thank very much.

Comment: Please define "don't work".

Comment: This does not work if the selected date is a date in the existing database
But if I put ( existing Date 1 if this filters ) .
Example : 16 / July / 2015 shows me the dates datatable 15 / July / 2015

this is so?

Also, once it filtered , if I delete the data entered in the calendar does not change the datatable
.any solution? thank you